# Azure functions v3 docker image based on alpine

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, azure-functions

For security reasons we don't want to use the default azure functions img, as that one and all .net core based imgs are based default on Debian. Alpine is from a security point of view much better. Debian has alot of vulnerabilities, where alpine has none.
More info on that subject here: https://ignas.me/tech/docker-image-vulnerabilities-in-net-core/

Anyhow, v2 of functions does have a alpine based docker img, v3 is missing it.

I was wondering why, as v3 exists for more than a year already.
Does anyone know about that or about a release data related to that?

Or sees another solution?

I tried and you could use the default v3 dockerfile, change it to use OS alpine.
But I don't know how well that has been tested (maybe there is an issue with v3 on alpine?), and we don't want to maintain it ourselves for every future version.